# How can i sum every N rows on maria db SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i'm having trouble of finding a way to perform simple addition on a table of maria db, SQL.

i'm having a table called Traffic:

```
| start_time        | end_time          | col1 | col2 |
| 1485075600.000000 | 1485075900.000000 | 10   | 20 |
| 1485075900.000000 | 1485076200.000000 | 20   | 30 |
| 1485076200.000000 | 1485076500.000000 | 40   | 50 |
| 1485076500.000000 | 1485076800.000000 | 50   | 60 |
```

How can i sum every N columns (over col1, and col2) ?

i mean, to merge rows and sum the values of col1, and col2.

assuming the given table, And N = 2, 
the result will be:

```
| start_time        | end_time          | col1 | col2|
| 1485075600.000000 | 1485076200.000000 | 30   | 50  |
| 1485076200.000000 | 1485076800.000000 | 90   | 110 |
```

if the table size isn't a multiple of of N, take all you can.

Any one have any idea? i don't have id's to group by on.

Comment: Which version?  I am thinking about the windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by enumerating the rows.  To be correct, you need a column to specify the ordering -- SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so they need a column for the ordering.

Let me assume it is `start_time`.  The rest is just aggregation and arithmetic:

```
select min(start_time) as start_time, max(end_time) as end_time,
       sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from traffic t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by start_time
     ) t
group by floor( (rn - 1) / @N);
```

The `@N` value is the size of the groups.

Comment: Thank you! Hey, for some reason, when i'm executing it, it is merging all the rows into one. can you explain please?

Comment: @Amit_A . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  I don't see an obvious error in the above code.  That would occur if you left out the `GROUP BY`, if `@rn` was not initialized properly, or if you don't se `@N` (just replace it with "2" if that is what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the response. i changed the N accordingly, but it won't change the results. here is a sqlfidle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5855/2